# Change threshold on the similarity index for git merge with renaming involved (like -M[n] --find-renames[=n] on diff)

Tags: git, dvcs

We have some configuration options for the rename detection heuristics during `diff` (`log`, `show`) and `merge`:

**diff.renameLimit**
The number of files to consider when performing the copy/rename detection; equivalent to the git diff option -l.

**diff.renames**
Tells git to detect renames. If set to any boolean value, it will enable basic rename detection. If set to "copies" or "copy", it will detect copies, as well.

**merge.renameLimit**
The number of files to consider when performing rename detection during a merge; if not specified, defaults to the value of diff.renameLimit.

Also we have an option to control when files with different contents are considered a rename for `diff` (`log`, `show`):

**-M[<n>]**
(or --find-renames[=<n>])

Detect renames. If n is specified, it is a threshold on the similarity index (i.e. amount of addition/deletions compared to the file’s size). For example, -M90% means git should consider a delete/add pair to be a rename if more than 90% of the file hasn’t changed.

**QUESTION**: How to control a threshold on the similarity index for merge? It seems to be available only as a command-line option for `diff` and some others but not `merge`. And no configuration key even for `diff`. Is it not applicable for `merge` for some reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're merging with the recursive merge strategy (default) you can use the rename-threshold option:

```
git merge -X rename-threshold=80 branch
```