# How to mark a file as not moved in git? Mark as separate file delete & file add in one commit

Tags: git

Sometimes I remove a JSON file and add another similar JSON file in an entire different path. The files have both around 10 lines. They are only different in 2 lines. If I add the new file & remove the old file in one commit git recognizes this as an move with some changes.

Is there some way to tell git that this wasn't a move?

(Why I want this: I have then a cleaner history & can avoid some merge conflicts)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/8826972/7976758

Answer (score 1):

Git does not store if you move or rename a file, it is actually detected on `git show` or `git log`, which you can use `--no-renames` to turn off the rename detection.

To make sure git always think they are different files, it is best to just remove and add the file in different commits.